# reading multiple parquet files in java takes unresonable amount of memory

Tags: java, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Reading 20 uncompressed parquet files with total size 3.2GB, takes more then 12GB in RAM, when reading them "concurrently".

"concurrently" means that I need to read the second file before closing the first file, not multithreading.

The data is time series, so my program needs to read all the files up to some time, and then proceed.

I expect Arrow to use the amount of memory that corresponds to a single batch multiplied by the amount of files, but in reality the memory used is much more then the entire files.

The files were created with pandas default config (using pyarrow), and reading them in java gives the correct values.

when reading each file to the fullest, and then closing the file, the amount of ram used is ok.

I have tried to switch between the netty, and unsafe memory jars but they have the same results.

`-Darrow.memory.debug.allocator=true` did not produce any error.

trying to limit the amount of direct memory (the excess memory is outside of the JVM) I have tried to replace `NativeMemoryPool.getDefault()` with
`NativeMemoryPool.createListenable(DirectReservationListener.instance())` or `NativeMemoryPool.createListenable(.. some custom listener ..)`

but the result is exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: JNIEnv was not attached to current thread
    at org.apache.arrow.dataset.jni.JniWrapper.nextRecordBatch(Native Method)
    at org.apache.arrow.dataset.jni.NativeScanner$NativeReader.loadNextBatch(NativeScanner.java:134)
    at ParquetExample.main(ParquetExample.java:47)
```

using `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1g`, `-Xmx4g` anyways had no effect.

the runtime is using env varibale:
`_JAVA_OPTIONS="--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED"`
on JDK 17.0.2 with arrow 9.0.0

the code is extracted to this simple example, taken from the official documentation:

```
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.file.FileFormat;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.file.FileSystemDatasetFactory;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.jni.NativeMemoryPool;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.scanner.ScanOptions;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.scanner.Scanner;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.source.Dataset;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.source.DatasetFactory;
import org.apache.arrow.memory.BufferAllocator;
import org.apache.arrow.memory.RootAllocator;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.VectorSchemaRoot;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ParquetExample {

    static BufferAllocator allocator = new RootAllocator(128 * 1024 * 1024); // limit does not affect problem

    public static ArrowReader read_parquet_file(Path filePath, NativeMemoryPool nativeMemoryPool) {
        String uri = "file:" + filePath;
        ScanOptions options = new ScanOptions(/*batchSize*/ 64 * 1024 * 1024);
        try (
                DatasetFactory datasetFactory = new FileSystemDatasetFactory(
                        allocator, nativeMemoryPool, FileFormat.PARQUET, uri);
                Dataset dataset = datasetFactory.finish()
        ) {
            Scanner scanner = dataset.newScan(options);
            return  scanner.scan().iterator().next().execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<VectorSchemaRoot> schemaRoots = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Path filePath : [...] ) { // 20 files, total uncompressed size 3.2GB
            ArrowReader arrowReader = read_parquet_file(file,
                    NativeMemoryPool.getDefault());
            if (arrowReader.loadNextBatch()) { // single batch read
                schemaRoots.add(arrowReader.getVectorSchemaRoot());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

the question is - why Arrow using so much memory in a straight-forward example, and why replacing the NativeMemoryPool results in crash?

Thanks